# Employing Version control on Android code

Tags: android, performance

My work is to store files from an android device to the cloud storage. However, for each file that is to be stored in cloud I want to employ version control which is independent of the cloud's version control mechanism. Is there any version control library or other mechanism available which can be used in the Android code ? I can guess for limited capacity android device enabling a version control mechanism may slow the application but in that case any suggestion regarding the way to maintain file even before sending them to cloud is very appreciated.

Comment: How about SVN or github?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.However do SVN and github has library like a SDK that can be added and used in the code ? I couldn't find any. I'm not concerned about the code maintenance.  I am thinking to maintain the file (that is the input of my code) using version control through my android code before sending them to cloud.

Comment: I would think you'd want to find a library that would let you do diffs on the files.  If you store the whole file for every version your storage requirements are going to get out of hand quickly.  Combine that with a sqlite database.  Why do you need to do your own version control rather than using the cloud service's?